# how to link subdomain to webserver on specific port?

Tags: dns, cloudflare

I have nodejs application running on port 2000 and domain is on cloudflare. Server works, when I search domain.example:2000 but I don't know how to add it to dns record or how to get rid of port in domain.
My domain is on cloudflare

Answer (score 0):

If you're hosting your domain on cloudflare, the easiest way is running a cloudflare tunnel from the host running the nodejs app. You need to add a route to proxy port 2000 from the webserver. The config of the CF tunnel would be something similar to this:

```
tunnel: 6f*****2-765d-4adf-8112-3**********f
credentials-file: /root/.cloudflared/6f*****2-765d-4adf-8112-3**********f.json

ingress:
  - hostname: your-host.your-domain.com
    service: http://localhost:2000
  - service: http_status:404
```

If you do the set-up using Zero Trust GUI, you don't even need a config file like the one above.

This playlist has a lot of examples explaining how to config the local environment and the cloudflare account: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLY4sFY6dmLqwQrcEHPnqVi8EayhdP7yLK